Optimal transition matrix that minimizes mixing time
For a finite state space, say I have a transition matrix $P$ such that it is irreducible and aperiodic. The stationary distribution is $\pi$. I wonder if there's any literature on how to pick an extra stochastic matrix $T$ such that $\pi P T =\pi$, and the mixing time of this new transition matrix $P T$ is the smallest (or the second largest eigenvalue in absolute value is minimized) among all other irreducible, aperiodic transition matrices that preserves $\pi$.
Thanks!

Note sure this answer your question (because I do not know what eigenvalue constraint you want), but how about $T=\lim_{n\to \infty} P^n$ ? In that case for any initial state $\tau$, $T\tau = \pi$ and so $PT\pi = \pi$ obviously. $T$ is actually equal to the rank one matrix $\pi \mathbf 1^\top$ by aperiodicity and irreducibility.

The smallest mixing time is trivial. It's the transition matrix that corresponds to the following procedure. 1. Discard the value you have right now. 2. Pick a value distributed from $\pi$. That's definitely unrealistic, so you need some condition to make your question more interesting.

A related practical question in computational Bayesian statistics consists in optimizing the mixing time of various Markov processes with a desired equilibrium distribution. I don't think there are many results with a wide application, but there are some. You can try searching for the convergence speed of the MALA algorithm (Metropolis Adjusted Langevin) when $\pi$ is log-concave / strongly log-concave

Good point! Thank you both @P.Quinton and Guillaume Dehaene. I am starting with finite state space looking at the changes of the spectral gaps after transition T, hoping to shed some light on the general state space case. Now that the optimal case is trivial, does there exist any theoretical result that characterizes the spectral gap of PT by spectral gap of P and some features of T?
